# Can I use "our" and "we" in a formal essay?

Tags: personal-pronouns

I am writing a formal essay, based on the following prompt

> Differing points of view make life interesting.

I am finding it hard to avoid using "our" and "we" in the essay. For example, in the following context:

> Humans have a wide range of interests and hobbies; we read different books, play different sports, engage in different conversations, and ultimately posses different convictions.

and

> Diversity is the catalyst for invention and innovation; it is absolutely necessary, and a vital part of the world we live in.

How can I avoid this in my essay? Or, is it fine to leave it that way?

**Is it incorrect to use "we" and/or "our" in a formal essay?**

Comment: Yes, "we" is fine here.  (Unless perhaps you personally are not a human; then you can say "they".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how formal you wish to take the essay

> Humans have a wide range of interests and hobbies; we read different
>   books, play different sports, engage in different conversations, and
>   ultimately posses different convictions.

could become

> Humans have a wide range of interests and hobbies, such as reading
>   different books, participation in sports, engagement in different
>   conversations, and ultimately posses different convictions.

Comment: '... reading taste in books, ...' Is making me wonder what reading tastes like and where can I experience this in books!

Answer (score 2):

You can include yourself or stand to the side.

> Humans have a wide range of interests and hobbies; *we* read different books, play different sports, engage in different conversations, and ultimately posses different convictions.

and

> Humans have a wide range of interests and hobbies; *they* read different books, play different sports, engage in different conversations, and ultimately posses different convictions.

Similarly

> Diversity is the catalyst for invention and innovation; it is absolutely necessary, and a vital part of the world *we* live in.

and

> Diversity is the catalyst for invention and innovation; it is absolutely necessary, and a vital part of the world *humans* [or *they*, if there is a prior reference] live in.

Correctness is dependent on the attitude of your audience.